# How can I force certain strings to be sorted last in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of strings alphabetically, except for certain strings (e.g. `"NA"` and `"Wild"`) that should always be placed last. The sorting priority should be `sorted_values_alphabetically < "NA" < "Wild"`.

If we have the following array:

```
["Wild", "sit", "ipsum", "dolor", "NA", "amet", "lorem"];
```

I would like it to be sorted as:

```
["amet", "dolor", "ipsum", "lorem", "sit", "NA", "Wild"];
```

I was thinking something like

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  var aVal = a, bVal = b;

  // Hack to make values < "NA" < "Wild"
  if (aVal == "NA") aVal = "zzz" + aVal;
  if (bVal == "NA") bVal = "zzz" + bVal;
  if (aVal == "Wild") aVal = "zzzz" + aVal;
  if (bVal == "Wild") bVal = "zzzz" + bVal;

  return aVal.toLowerCase().localeCompare(bVal.toLowerCase());
});
```

But this probably wouldn't work for all Unicode characters.

I'm also interested in performant algorithms!

#### Performance

Just FYI, T. J. Crowder's algorithm is slightly more performant via [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-24290131). Altohugh I prefer Halcyon's more concise approach!

Comment: Just return something greater than zero when you need to, or less than zero if it's `"NA"` vs. `"Wild"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an exception to your sorting function. With a little clever Math I got:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
     var exceptions = [ "NA", "Wild" ], indexA, indexB;
     indexA = exceptions.indexOf(a);
     indexB = exceptions.indexOf(b);
     if (indexA === -1 && indexB === -1) {
         return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase()); // regular case
     }
     return indexA - indexB; // index will be -1 (doesn't occur), 0 or 1
});
```

Answer (score 2):

So basically, all strings are less than `"Wild"`, and all strings except `"Wild"` are less than `"NA"`. The function you pass into `sort` should return a negative number if `a < b`, `0` if `a == b`, or a positive number if `a > b`. So you handle the special cases by returning appropriate values:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {

  // Everything is less than "Wild"
  if (a === "Wild") {
    return 1;  // a is greater than b
  }
  if (b === "Wild") {
    return -1; // b is greater than a
  }

  // Everything else is less than "NA"
  if (a === "NA") {
    return 1;  // a is greater than b
  }
  if (b === "NA") {
    return -1; // b is greater than a
  }

  // Normal result
  return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(a.toLowerCase());
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/roluhiba/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/roluhiba/1/edit))

*(Obviously, the detailed comments make that look longer than it actually is...)*

Comment: In your special cases you need to check the other value as well, the exceptions have an order too, `"NA"` comes before `"Wild"`

Comment: @Halcyon: The logic above does that as a by-product of checking `"Wild"` first. Here's an example with `"NA"` and `"Wild"` in various different places; the end result ends up with all the `"NA"`s before the `"Wild"`s: http://jsbin.com/roluhiba/2

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! There's a typo on the last line (the last `a.toLowerCase()` should be `b.toLowerCase()`)